# where to fill host and scheme while connecting to server http

Tags: android

I am learning how to connect my app to server through http so I am following up this [tutorial](http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/)

I got this error.

```
06-26 00:21:52.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2685):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-26 00:21:52.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2685): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=justedhak.comlu.com/cnct.php
06-26 00:21:52.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2685):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:2490)
```

So I understand host and scheme are null , how should I fill them ? and what do they mean by sheme ?

this is there code.

```
package com.example.asynchttppost;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.Visibility;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText value;
    private Button btn;
    private ProgressBar pb;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);
        value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(value.getText().toString().length()<1){

                // out of range
                Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString());      
            }


    } 

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postData(params[0]);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
            pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://somewebsite.com/receiver.php");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a URL that doesn't start with the scheme (http:// or https://).  Fix that, and everything should work.  A simple fix would be to check if the URL starts with one of those two, and if it doesn't prepend http://

Comment: oh thanks I didnt notice that , I am beginner to server side